# An electronic device has an exponentially distributed lifetime, with an average of 5 years

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

An electronic device has an exponentially distributed lifetime, with an average of $5$ years. What is the period within which $5$% of the first to decompose, do so?

I know that $\lambda=\frac{1}{5}$ because the expected lifetime is 5 and its an exponential distribution

but i cant understand the question at all, is asking for quantile?

Answer (score 1):

If it's an introductory material, then my interpretation agrees with yours, that the question is asking:

"What is the period within which $5$% of the devices decompose?"

It is worded in such a way to emphasize that the whole process is random, and we don't know which ones will decompose.

Thus the desired answer is the point where the exponential tail is $95$%, for the rate $\lambda = 1/5$ years.